# NodeJS Linux Ubuntu running Issue

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, socket.io, ubuntu-16.04

When I am closing putty so I am closing connection ,my nodejs is going to off. How can I solve it ?

but when terminal closed, my node server is stopped.
I have express, socket.io and nodemon services. I am running from nodemon.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
sudo apt-get install npm
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
node myServer.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You are running `node` as a child process of your shell. Once the shell is terminated, all of its children are also terminated, in your case - the `node` server. To detach it from the shell, you can run it in the background by using the `&` operator:

```
$ node myServer.js &
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forever` module. you can find the npm repo [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)

Install globally `npm install -g forever`

Simple start `forever start myServer.js`

You can also send all your logs to a file like this `forever start -a -o out.log -l forever.log -e err.log myServer.js`. This will send the stderr logs to a err.log file and stdout logs to out.log

You can use this with the `Debug` [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) and that way get all the logs from debug. `DEBUG=* forever start -a -o out.log -l forever.log -e err.log myServer.js`

Restart your server `forever restart 0`. `0` is the number of the instance you are running.

Stop an instance `forever stop 0`

Check out the docs for many more great options